# How to use for Each to add specific values in json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a json structure like,

```
$scope.inputs.data=[{name:"sam",marks:"100"},{name:"don",
marks:"200"}]
```

How can we add all the marks using forEach.can someone help ..I was trying this way but no luck

```
var i=0;
angular.forEach($scope.inputs.data,function(value){
var sum=o;
var tot=sum+value.marks[i];
i++     
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and summ the total value from the property.

```js
var $scope = { inputs: { data: [{ name: "sam", marks: "100" }, { name: "don", marks: "200" }] } },
    total = $scope.inputs.data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        return r + +o.marks;
    }, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Solution with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var $scope = { inputs: { data: [{ name: "sam", marks: "100" }, { name: "don", marks: "200" }] } },
    total = 0;

$scope.inputs.data.forEach(function (o) {
    total += +o.marks;
});

console.log(total);
```

Comment: @Nina Here I just gave 2 array objects in json..But we cant have fixed..So I was using for Each..How to achieve this using forEach

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.inputs.data=[{name:"sam",marks:"100"},{name:"don",marks:"200"}];  

var sum=0;
$scope.inputs.data.forEach(function(value){

sum=sum+Number(value.marks);
 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`angular.foreach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach),You could do,

```
$scope.tot = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.inputs.data, function(value) {
 $scope.tot += parseInt(value.marks);
});
```

**`DEMO`**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>angular material switch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   Total is : {{tot}}
  </div>
  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
 <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
          $scope.inputs= {};
          $scope.inputs.data = [{
            name: "sam",
            marks: "100"
          }, {
            name: "don",
            marks: "200"
          }];
          $scope.tot = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.inputs.data, function(value) {
              $scope.tot += parseInt(value.marks);

            });
          });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```